# Python 3.9 and pip-3.9 on FreeBSD 12.2

Tags: package-management, python, freebsd, pip

I'm facing a confusing situation. The official latest fully-supported version of Python is 3.9, and while it's available in FreeBSD `pkg`, `pip-3.9` isn't, and I'll be needing it in the future when Python 3.7 reaches EOL.

In short:

- Python 3.7: available,
- Python 3.9: available,
- pip 3.7: availabe,
- pip 3.9: not available.

I skimmed through FreeBSD handbook and relevant FreeBSD wiki pages, but there doesn't seem to be an explanation. So what's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of binary packages distributed by the FreeBSD Project, which you can install with [pkg(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&sektion=8&n=1), includes Python packages for only one Python version at a time (which is Python 3.7 at the moment as you can see in the [Mk/bsd.default-versions.mk](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-ports/blob/e0b4e7a51346c5e32eaf788953b9af7b7f31b801/Mk/bsd.default-versions.mk#L104-L108) file in the [FreeBSD Ports tree](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-ports)). That's why you only see the Python 3.7 flavor of pip available in the package repository (i.e., `py37-pip`).

Users, who desire to use a different Python version for their FreeBSD packages, can build the packages from source. The default version of Python can be set in [make.conf(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?make.conf) as follows:

```
DEFAULT_VERSIONS=python=3.9 python3=3.9
```

If you decide to follow this path, I recommend using [poudriere](https://github.com/freebsd/poudriere) to set up your own package repository. This is the official FreeBSD tool for building packages. Also, it's worth noting that building from source is generally well supported in FreeBSD.

If adding poudriere to your infrastructure is too high of a cost, then I'd just create a virtual environment for Python and then install the desired pip version there.

I advise against running `pip install --upgrade pip` as root since it is going to pollute your system. The reason is that you are going to upgrade `pip` you installed with `pkg` with `pip`. This may lead to unexpected inconsistencies on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, I'd suggest installing pip 3.7 and then using it to upgrade itself via

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

This looks the same as [How do I update pip itself from inside my virtual environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment) on StackOverflow.

Comment: But then I'll have to keep both python37 and python39 on my installation, because removing python37 also removes pip-3.7 (using the `pkg` command).

Comment: That's somewhat acceptable if I'm able to install pip packages into `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`, so could you expand your answer on this aspect?

Comment: I may have overlooked something (not unprecedented) but I believe pip is just another PyPI package. Upgrading Python should not touch your packages, unless you otherwise *need* more than one version of Python3?

Comment: I don't need more than 1 version of Python. But I do desire my PyPi packages to be installed in the `site-packages` directory of the **correct version of** Python library directory. Which is why I need a pip with a version matching that of python.